# crear un array nuevo que contenga la letra que introduzcamos por teclado

Tags: java, array

Buenas mi código es el siguiente y quiero que al introducir una letra me muestre en un array nuevo con las palabras que contenga esa letra EL NUEVO ARRAY NO PUEDE DEVOLVER NULL
por ejemplo si introduzco H me devuelva un nuevo string con Hola y Hipopotamo sin NULL

```
 String[] array1 = {Hola,Adios,hipopotamo}

 public static String[] letraPresente(String [] array1, char letra) {
        
    String[] arrayFinal = new String[array1.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
        if (array1[i].contains(""+letra)) {
            arrayFinal[i] = ("["+array1[i]+"] ");
        }if (arrayFinal[i]!=null) {
            return arrayFinal[i];
        }}return arrayFinal;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero obtenemos el numero de palabras que contienen la letra dada,para así declarar el  tamaño del nuevo arreglo,mediante un for,con otro ciclo repetitivo, al saber que vamos a tener en una posición con null,por si solo dos o una palabra contienen la letra dada,ponemos una condicional que valide que solo queremos los datos diferente a null y así llenamos el nuevo arreglo

```
import java.util.Arrays;


public class Test{

public static String [] letraEnPalabras(String []array,char letra){
int cont=0;
for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
  if(array[i].contains(String.valueOf(letra))){
        cont++;
  }
}

String []aux=new String[cont];
int m=0;

for(int j=0;j<array.length;j++){
  if(array[j].contains(String.valueOf(letra))){
    if(array[j]!=null){
        aux[m]=array[j];
        m++;
    }
  }

}
  return aux;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String[] array1 = {"Hola","Adios","hipopotamo"};
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(letraEnPalabras(array1,'H')));

}}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]